# MySQL + PHP: Select all results from one table for each result of another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following two tables in my database:

```
TABLE 1: Specials
---------------------------------------------
| Special ID | Special Name | Special Image |
 --------------------------------------------
|     1      |   Special 1  |     1.jpg     |   
|     2      |   Special 2  |     2.jpg     |
|     3      |   Special 3  |     3.jpg     |
---------------------------------------------

TABLE 2: Special Items
---------------------------
| Item ID | Item Name     |
---------------------------
|     1      |   Service  | 
|     2      |    Clean   |
|     3      |     Dry    |
---------------------------
```

When pulled from the database I am looking for a way to achieve this (Column 4 will be a drop down list):

```
EDIT SPECIALS (Columns 1-3: Table 1) (Column 4: All results from Table 2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Special ID | Special Name | Special Image | Items               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |   Special 1  |     1.jpg     | Service, Clean, Dry |      
|     2      |   Special 2  |     2.jpg     | Service, Clean, Dry | 
|     3      |   Special 3  |     3.jpg     | Service, Clean, Dry |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of `MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()` method which is able to concatenate rows.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ItemName) FROM SpecialItems) ItemList
FROM    Specials a
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98daa/1)
- [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ SPECIAL ID ║ SPECIAL NAME ║ SPECIAL IMAGE ║     ITEMLIST      ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║          1 ║ Special 1    ║ 1.jpg         ║ Service,Clean,Dry ║
║          2 ║ Special 2    ║ 2.jpg         ║ Service,Clean,Dry ║
║          3 ║ Special 3    ║ 3.jpg         ║ Service,Clean,Dry ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: You can also use `SEPARATOR` to include a space after the commas: `(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ItemName) FROM SpecialItems SEPARATOR ', ')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCATE` MySQL that will help you to combine result with comma separations.

**<kbd>[`Example`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)</kbd>**